# Music.app creating playlists gratuitously

Tags: music, playlist

I have seen these duplicate playlists many times:

[image]

I never use any of them, and frequently delete all four, only to have them reappear the next time Music is launched.  When I delete them, they stay away until exit, but they are there at the beginning of the next session.  Today, I deleted all four and exited Music immediately and re-launched it.  There they are, with no sync of any devices.  iCloud music library is OFF and has been all along.  This has been happening for many versions of Music and MacOS, and on at least two different laptops.  On 26 June 2023, there were **four** of each, but that quickly went back to two.

Apple has been silent on the bug report that I made in February 2022, **so I thought I’d check here whether anyone knows the cause and/or the fix**.

Comment: Recently, our daughter added us to her Apple Music, which prompted me to turn on iCloud sync.  But that caused problems, the biggest being songs being removed fr4om an iPad (even though it had lots of empty space).  So I turned it off again.  But that did not cause this problem, which started LONG before iCloud was turned on and off.

Comment: Are you logged in to your iCloud account in the Music app? If that's the case,  logging out with Account > Sign Out may help fix the problem. (It's a shame that Apple hasn't invested more time and effort in improving the usability of the Music app... I've had problems with duplicated and "undeletable" playlists too, and have finally given up and stopped using the Music app altogether.)

Comment: The sign-on and logout in Music are for the store, not for iCloud.  And, as I said, the behavior was happening LONG BEFORE I enabled iCloud sync and Apple Music.